# Get results within x miles Using GeoCoordinate with respository pattern

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, geolocation, repository-design

I would like to get a list of all organisations within x miles of a location entered by the user. This is converted to a long/lat location.

Organisations are stored in the database with long and lat.

I am using MVC with entity framework and a Unit of Work with the respository pattern to access the dataset.

Here is my EntityRepository:

```
        public IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            return dbSet;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

To query the data in my datacontext I use a service class for each entity, a UOW is injected into each service. The service call for organisations is:

```
 public class OrgService :IOrgService
{
    private IUnitOfWork _UoW;

    public OrgService(IUnitOfWork UoW)
    {
        _UoW = UoW;
    }

    public Organisation GetOrgByID(int OrgID)
    {

        return _UoW.OrganisationRepo.Find(OrgID);
    }

    public IList<Organisation> GetAllOrgs()
    {
        return _UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.ToList();  
    }

    public IList<Organisation> GetOrgsByLocation(double lat, double lng, int range)
    {

      /// I need to return a list of all organisations within X miles

    }

 }
```

All other queries are working as the they should however I am no trying to write the method GetOrgsByLocation(). This is the query I think I need to get my results:

```
 var userLocation = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lng);
 var result = _UoW.OrganisationRepo.Where(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
                              .Where(x => x.GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList();
```

When I try to run this query I get:

***"cannot implicitly convert type system.device.location.geoCoordinate to bool"***

Can anyone help?

** Update - Working solution **

```
 var userLocation = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lng);
        var nearbyOrganizations = _UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.ToList()
         .Select(x => new
         { //use an anonymous type or any type you want
             Org = x,
             Distance = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude).GetDistanceTo(userLocation)
         }) 
         .Where(x => x.Distance < 50000)
         .ToList();

        foreach (var organisation in nearbyOrganizations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1:n0} meters)", organisation.Org, organisation.Distance);
        }
```

Thanks to the help below for this solution, though it seems all objects have to be queried in orfer for this to work, it seems that query would be better suited to run on the database, I'll have to look into this more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Where` method has to return a boolean value.

```
_UoW.OrganisationRepo.Where(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
```

Maybe you meant to use a `.Select` there? Would the following code work?

```
_UoW.OrganisationRepo.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
                          .Where(x => x.GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList();
```

Be aware that Entity Framework tries to generate some SQL from the expression provided. I'm afraid that `x.GetDistanceTo(userLocation)` might not work inside the .Where expression, unless you cast it to an `IEnumerable`, or call .`AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` before calling `.Where`. Or maybe EF is smart enough to see that `GeoCoordinate` is not mapped to a table, and then stop generating the SQL right there.

#### Edit

The code you commented won't work:

```
_UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude).GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList()
```

Notice that you're selecting a list of bools because you're selecting the results instead of filtering by them. You won't know which organizations are within the radius. That's why we use .Select and .Where separately.

Try something like this:

```
_UoW.OrganisationRepo.All
     .Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
     .ToEnumerable() //or .ToList() or .ToArray(), make sure it's outside of EF's reach (prevent SQL generation for this)
     .Where(x=> x.GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList()
```

However, if you want to know which organizations are within the radius, you'll need to carry more information along the path.

```
var nearbyOrganizations = _UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.ToList()
     .Select(x => new 
      { //use an anonymous type or any type you want
          Org = x, 
          Distance = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude).GetDistanceTo(userLocation) 
     }) //it's probably outside EF's SQL generation step by now, but you could add one more .Select here that does the math if it fails (return the GeoCoordinate object)
     .Where(x=> x.Distance < radius)
     .ToList();
```

Seems like it would be useful for you to know more about .Where and .Select. They're super useful. .Where is essentialy a filter, and .Select transforms objects. And due to anonymous types, you can do whatever you want.

Notice that this will fetch all objects from the database. You probably want to use native features of the database to work with geographical data, and EF probably supports it.

Comment: Thanks for this, the select you suggested will not work as this is not implemented by the Repository. I've updated the query as suggested by Darren and I'm now running into the problem you suggest.

Comment: Is it possible to implement .Select on the repository? Either way, would the following code work? `_UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.Select(...).ToEnumerable()[or .ToArray/List()].Where(...)`

It's not clear what is the interface for OrganisationRepo. .Select and .Where usually go hand in hand, it's definitely weird not having .Select...

Comment: Yeah I can implement a Select like so: _UoW.OrganisationRepo.All.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude).GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList(); Still getting an error as it seems a List<bool> is being returned.

Comment: The OrganisationRepo is just mapped to the Organisation Domain class, so nothing strange there

Comment: @Dez79 I was reviewing my own code, I messed up in the edit, but I think the current one should work. However, it will end up getting every single object from the database, which is probably not what you want. Maybe if you put the math directly in the Where expression would be more performant

Comment: Thanks for this..its now pulling out the data I want! I was getting a bit confused in that it wasn't pulling back a list of organisations, but it now makes sense. however as you say, I cant have it pulling out all objects and may have to look at another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with your first `Where` as you are trying to create a new GeoCoordinate class and `Where` is expecting a bool output from the lambda not a GeoCoordinate instance.

I would suggest making the following change:

```
var result = _UoW.OrganisationRepo.Where(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude).GetDistanceTo(userLocation) < radius).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of Organisations back within the radius you are interested in.

**Update**

The prior won't work with IQueryable as the provider will not be able to create an SQL query because the .GetDistanceTo function is not known within SQL.

As an alternative could you not use the Spatial Data types in EF 5 onwards?

This blog post by Rick Strahl gives an example of querying geography data stored in SQL by distance from a given location

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/jun/21/basic-spatial-data-with-sql-server-and-entity-framework-50

Comment: If `OrganisationRepo` is an `IQueryable<T>` tied to Entity Framework, perhaps it will have some trouble generating the SQL query. Should be fine for LINQ to Objects though.

Comment: Good point. The only other alternatives would be to either project into a tuple and do the where after (but then you end up negating and performance boosts from query generation) or Writing the where to do the calculation for the distance manually so that it can be transformed into an SQL query by EF

Comment: And my solution also doesn't work because of the same reason.

Comment: I've updated the query and the solution now builds however I've ran into the problem suggested above and get the following error. Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double GetDistanceTo(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I would also argue to let the database calculate the distances if at all possible, so you wont need to do the whole IQueryable->IEnumerable dance.